# How to create animation from raster data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, erdas-imagine, envi, ndvi, animation

I have some NDVI and precipitation/temperature images at the monthly time step from Jan, 2005 to Dec, 2008.

I need to create animation image to show the temporal change.

How can I do this?

Is it possible to use ArcGIS, ERDAS, ENVI? 
If so, please tell me the processes step by step? 
If not, what software and tool can be used to do this?

Answer (score 7):

ArcGIS 10 Animation
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_an_animation/000900000001000000/

ArcGIS 10 Temporal Data
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_temporal_data_management_and_visualization/005z00000021000000/

**You can record either and export to either image (animated gifs) or video (avi)**

Comment: Here's another blog post from the ESRI Support Services - "Do your rasters know what time it is?" from 6.1.11:

http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2011/06/01/test.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ENVI, it's straightforward. You can find out how to do it [here](http://geol.hu/data/online_help/Creating_Animations.html)

Given that your datasets are univariate (NDVI, temperature, pecipitation), you may want to encode them into an RGB composite dataset and plot a single "map" for each timestep.

Answer (score 1):

One newer possibility available in GRASS7

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/g.gui.animation.html